# Oracle SQL - How to return records with the earliest/min date per each ID

Tags: sql, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query that will currently return multiple records because the date is slightly different amongst them.  I would like to return the record with earliest date per ID.

Example output:

```
ID  AMOUNT  DATE
1   10      1
1   20      2
1   30      3
1   1       4
2   34      1
2   234     2
2   234     3
2   34      4
3   3       1
3   3       2
3   23      3
3   20      4
```

Desired output:

```
ID  AMOUNT  DATE
1   10      1
2   34      1
3   3       1
```

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT th.somefield21 as field21, 
th.somefield18 AS field18, 
th.somefield17 AS field17, 
(c.somefield19 || ' ' || c.somefield20) AS field19, 
CASE when th.somefield15 = 'TEST' then (b.apple || ' ' || b.bananna || ' ' || b.peach || ' ' || b.plum || ' ' || b.grape) else a.somefield16 END AS field16, 
a.somefield1 AS field1, 
a.somefield2 AS field2, 
a.somefield3 AS field3, 
th.somefield4 AS field4, 
s.somefield5 AS field5, 
th.somefield6 AS field6, 
th.somefield7 AS field7, 
th.somefield8 AS field8, 
s.somefield9 AS field9, 
s.somefield10 AS field10, 
s.somefield11 AS field11, 
s.somefield12 AS field12, 
s.somefield13 AS field13, 
th.somefield14 AS field14 
FROM schema.therm th, 
schema.charlie c, 
schema.faux f, 
schema.alpha a, 
schema.bravo b, 
schma.sierra s, 
schema.delta d, 
schema.golf g, 
schema.echo e, 
schema.foxtrot ft 
  WHERE ft.act='submit' 
     AND ft.tid = th.tid  
     AND ft.aid = c.aid 
     AND c.cid = f.cid 
     AND f.addid = a.addid 
     AND f.addid = b.addid 
     AND th.tid = d.tid 
     AND ft.aid = e.aid
     AND e.dsrid = g.dsrid 
     AND g.dsprid = s.dsprid 
     AND th.ttype = 'c1' 
     AND f.add = 'wookie' 
     AND th.date between to_date('01/01/2001 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and to_date('10/01/2019 23:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
     AND s.code = 'han' 
     AND th.state != 'darth' 
     AND d.act NOT IN ('peach','pear','cherry','plum') 
ORDER BY th.field21;
```

Which results in multiple records for entries with the same ID.

I tried adding `min(th.somefield18 AS field18,)` but that resulted in

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function".
```

When I attempt to add `GROUP BY field19` it results in

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
```

Comment: I cannot fathom what your query has to do with the initial question.  One is so simple.  The other . . .

Comment: Will `SELECT * FROM ( your_query ) WHERE date = 1` do what you want? And if the value really isn't `1` then use one of the solutions from the linked duplicates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The query looks more complicated in its obfuscated form.  I am pulling together fields to create a report and unfortunately to get to the required data involves a fair amount of linking to a bunch or tables.  It could no doubt be done in cleaner manner, but I am a novice at SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.date = (
    select min(t1.date)
    from mytable t1
    where t1.id = t.id
)
```

With an index on `(id, date)`, this should have good efficiency.

Another option is to use a window function to rank the records within groups of records having the same `id`, and then filter on the top record per group:

```
select id, date
from (
    select t.*, rank() over(partition by t.id order by t.date) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Note: your query is *much* more complicated than your sample data. This answers to the use case described in your sample data.

Comment: GMB, thank you.  The correlated subquery solved it.  I had attempted to use a subquery previously but was unsuccessful.  Thank you again.